# How do I find the coordinates of a point on a circle in PyGame?

Tags: python, math, pygame

If a sprite is in the centre of a circle at the point 250,250 in pygame what is the equation to find the edge of the circle in any direction relative to the original point. Could the equation have the angle (as X) in the equation?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried typing the "equation of circle" into a search engine? What happened? What did you not understand about the formula you found?

Comment: This is straightforward trigonometry. See for example https://courses.lumenlearning.com/boundless-algebra/chapter/trigonometric-functions-and-the-unit-circle/

Comment: As we learn in high school geometry, the equation is `x^2 + y^2=r^2`. We also lean how to calculate this with angles and offsets

Comment: `(x - 250)^2 + (y - 250)^2 = radius ^ 2`

Comment: `x = r * cos(theta) + 250, y = r * sin(theta) + 250`. Are these what you are looking for?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos that equation defines the set of points on the circumference of the circle, but it does not help the OP find a point on the circle at a given angle.

Comment: @Rabbid76 thanks but (a potentially stupid question) what do the new x and y equal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The general formula is `(x, y) = (cx + r * cos(a), cy + r * sin(a))`.

However, in your case ° is at the top and the angle increases clockwise. Therefore the formula is:

```py
angle_rad = math.radians(angle)
pt_x = cpt[0] + radius * math.sin(angle_rad)
pt_y = cpt[1] - radius * math.cos(angle_rad)
```

Alternatively, you can use the [`pygame.math`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector2) module and [`pygame.math.Vector2.rotate`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector2.rotate):

```py
vec = pygame.math.Vector2(0, -radius).rotate(angle)
pt_x, pt_y = cpt[0] + vec.x, cpt[1] + vec.y
```

---

Minimal example:

[image]

```py
import pygame
import math

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 40)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
cpt = window.get_rect().center
angle = 0
radius = 100

run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False  

    # solution 1
    #angle_rad = math.radians(angle)
    #pt_x = cpt[0] + radius * math.sin(angle_rad)
    #pt_y = cpt[1] - radius * math.cos(angle_rad)    
    
    # solution 2
    vec = pygame.math.Vector2(0, -radius).rotate(angle)
    pt_x, pt_y = cpt[0] + vec.x, cpt[1] + vec.y
    
    angle += 1     
    if angle >= 360:
        angle = 0

    window.fill((255, 255, 255))
    pygame.draw.circle(window, (0, 0, 0), cpt, radius, 2)
    pygame.draw.line(window, (0, 0, 255), cpt, (pt_x, pt_y), 2)
    pygame.draw.line(window, (0, 0, 255), cpt, (cpt[0], cpt[1]-radius), 2)
    text = font.render(str(angle), True, (255, 0, 0))
    window.blit(text, text.get_rect(center = cpt))
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
exit()
```

Comment: @JacobBoughton This is just the math how the point (x, y)  is computed, it is not a python expression. The code would be `x = cx + r * math.cos(a)`, `y = cy + r * math.sin(a)`

Comment: Should `pt_x, pt_y = cpt[0] + vec.x, cpt[0] + vec.y` be `pt_x, pt_y = cpt[0] + vec.x, cpt[1] + vec.y`, with the second `cpt` pointing to 1 instead of 0?